# Using tailwind css, how to spin an absolutely positioned and centered element?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using tailwind css, I can center an absolutely positioned element in its relative container: `<svg class="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">...</svg>`

Using tailwind css, I can make an absolutely positoined element spin: `<svg class="absolute animate-spin">...</svg>`

But when I try to center an absolutely positioned spinning element, `<svg class="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 animate-spin">...</svg>`, instead of spinning, the non-spinning element just moves down and to the right at a -45deg angle.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tailwind uses this css:

```
animate-spin:   animation: spin 1s linear infinite;

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

and also

```
-translate-x-1/2    transform: translateX(-50%);
-translate-y-1/2    transform: translateY(-50%);
```

**Solution:** I think this behavior is because spin and translate both manipulate transform property.
so you can wrap the svg in a div and set position related classes to that div and for svg only use animation class:

```
<div class="absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2">
   <svg class="animate-spin">...</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Came to this same conclusion and answered myself without refreshing and seeing your answer. Accepted your answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, when you use both translation classes, i.e., `-translate-x-1/2` and `-translate-y-1/2` with the class `animate-spin`, it is very likely to cause this behavior.

**Solution**: A solution approach would be to also use `transform` class along with the above 3 mentioned classes.

**Reason**: By adding `transform` class, it ensures that the two translational classes are grouped for performing transformation rather than changing position.

In this way, the element will have the properties of both center and spin as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, after adding "transform" I continue to observe the same unexpected result.

Comment: If this is not working try adding "left-1/2" and "top-1/2" to center the element and then add the "transform" and "animate-spin" classes.

If this doesn't work as per please try re-checking the Tailwind CSS setup so as to avoid any conflicts in CSS code

Answer (score 0):

'-translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2' include an associated 'transform', but 'animate-spin' also includes a 'transform' within a @keyframe.

It seems that these two transforms collide without being merged, possibly depending on the order of the keywords.

My workaround: a wrapper element

```
<div class="absolute left-1/2 right-1/2 -transform-x-1/2 -transform-y-1/2">
   <svg class="aninate-spin">...</svg>
</div>
```